Script for resolving \ifbool statements
In my tex documents, I am frequently using the etoolbox package, and in particular the command \ifbool{<bool>}{<true>}{<false>}.
I'd like to have an automated way of replacing these statements by the actual content, based on given values for booleans. My usecase is that all bools except one can be assumed to be set to false, hence the necessary input would be a tex file and the name of the boolean that should be interpreted as true in \ifbool statements.
Example input:
Hello \ifbool{alice}{Alice}{Bob}!
\ifbool{alice}{Content can span over
several lines.}{Also, it may contain
braces { like this }, so it is important
to find the right closing brace.}

Cooresponding output (with alice set true):
Hello Alice!
Content can span over
several lines.

I'm thinking of a bash script to achieve this (but my bash knowledge is not sufficient...), but any other technology will do, as well.

I'm not sure this is really the right site for this? Which OS are you on? Do you have sed? gawk? Is there a maximum number of brace groups inside?

With gawk I'd use a pattern match for \\ifbool as the input record separator. Then keep count of opening and closing braces, I guess, until you find a match. Then do it twice more, do the substitution and print the result. I've never done exactly this, but gawk is powerful if you have a little patience with it.gawk is better than sed for multiline records.

Thanks! I was hoping for a tool that does the brace matching for me, but counting by hand is definitely an option, as well. There is no maximum number of brace groups inside, but there might be a lot. I am on a Linux system, so using the tools you proposed is not an issue.

The gpp answer looks much nicer ;). There is also a good chance you can just install a package from your Linux distro, so really looks pretty straightforward. (This is assuming gpp can swallow whatever is inside your bool conditionals, of course,) I would try that first before resorting to gawk, at least.
